# Doubt in applying KVL

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I want to apply KVL to loops **abcda** and **befcb** in the circuit given below. Is there any role of the 2A current source in those two loops, that I need to consider before applying KVL?

[image]

Comment: In one way, it is three loops, not two. You can convert the \$2\:\text{A}\$ source and the \$5\:\Omega\$ impedance into a Thevenin source, I suppose, reducing it to two loops. Do you understand me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there any role of the 2A current source in those two loops, that I
> need to consider before applying KVL?*

If you convert the 2 amp source and the 5 Ω parallel resistor to an equivalent 10 volt voltage source (Thevenin and Norton theorems) you get this: -

[image]

And clearly there is a role played by the 10 volt source hence, there is a definite role played by the 2 amp source.

<sub>Can you see that you can simplify the equivalent circuit by combining the 5  and 10 Ω resistors and find a solution with more ease; there are only two loops now for instance. However, I'd continue using source transformations (Thevenin and Norton theorems) until you had the voltage at node b with respect to node c.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The current source makes a loop, too. Think there's the 3rd loop current I3 through it and the 5 ohm resistor. Fortunately I3 is known to be = 2A, the 3rd loop does not generate new unknown. Write the equations for loop currents I1 and I2 as you wanted. The equation for loop abcda has voltage (I1-2A) * 5 ohm over section da.

The result, of course, is finally the same as what's got by converting the current source to equivalent voltage source, but the basic idea is very different. I didn't suggest a network transformation. I said: Let the 3rd loop be and calculate with the KVL method as you planned.

Comment: Just in case there is any misunderstanding, the question raised was about the validity of  role of the 2 amp current source.

Comment: @Andy aka No problem. I wrote "voltage (I1-2A) * 5 ohm over section da" as the role and didn't at all start by modifying questioner's circuit like the others did.